# error bound for taylor expansion of ln(x) for $ x<= 1 $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

Given $f(x) = log(x) $ I want to find an error bound for the Taylor expansion around the point $ a = 1 $ for $x <= 1$. Using either the lagrange or the cauchy form of the error estimate, I want to prove for the error $|R_{1}^{m}f(x)|$ that  $ |R_{1}^{m}f(x)| \leqslant\frac{1}{x}|x-1|^{m+1}$. The cauchy form I want to use is 
$$|R_{1}^{m}f(x)| \leqslant \frac{|x-1|}{m!} \sup_{l\in(x,1)} |(x-l)^mf^{(m+1)}(l)| $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $f^{(m+1)}(t) = \frac{(-1)^m m!}{t^{m+1}}$, so your bound is given by the supremum of $(1 - x)t^{-1}(1 - x/t)^m$ for $t \in (x,1)$. But $t^{-1} \leq 1/x$ and $1 - x/t \leq 1 - x$, so the error is bounded by $\frac{1}{x}(1 - x)^{m+1}$.